# Why cant it find the id value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I am making an app that takes some URL by a JSON file and based on those URLs, get some data from SoundCloud API. So far there is no problem. but when it is loading the data, it put each one of them in a `<li>` tag. and each tag will have a id value based on the gathered data. Now I want to get get the value of each clicked `<li>` tag. But it does not work. I think because it is made dynamically, but do not know any solution for it.

here is my code for loading data: and then the function for showing clicked `<li>` in console:

```
$.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){
                var track = answer[val.URL];
                var trackTitle = track.title;
                
                    $(".playerList .list").append(
                    "<li id=" + track.id +">" + 
                    "<h3 class=\"songTitle\">" + track.title + "</h3>" +
                    "</li>");
});

$(".playerList .list li").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And this is the demo for full code: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/3JsJe/3/

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write event for li inside class list and have to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as li are generated dynamically via ajax, do like this:

```
    $(".playerList .list").on('click','li',function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XyY98/)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since you are appending those elements at runtime.

```
$(".playerList .list").on('click','.playerList .list li',function(){
 console.log(this.id); 
});
```